# Edit a cell in the table save to the django model

Tags: django, angular, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a table of employees. I am loading data using $http and using ng-repeat to print it on the webpage. I want to edit each row content.
HTML:

```
tbody ng-repeat="list in data" >
                    <tr ng-hide="edit" ng-click="edit=true">

                            {% verbatim %}
                            <td> {{$index + 1}}</td>
                            <td>{{ list.associate_nbr }}</td>
                            <td>{{ list.per }}%</td>
                            <td>{{ list.count }}</td>
                            <td>{{ list.sample_per }}%</td>
                            <td>{{ list.sample}}</td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="{{ list.focused 
                             }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="{{ 
                            list.random_field }}"></td>

                </tr>
                {% endverbatim %}
```

MAIN.JS

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
     angular.module('sampling.demo',[])
     .controller('SamplingController', ['$scope','$http',SamplingController]);
     function SamplingController($scope,$http)
     {

        $scope.data = [];
        $http.get('/sample/').then(function(response){

        $scope.data = response.data;
        });

     }
}());
```

I want to edit the last two  fields when user clicks on it.

Comment: You need to edit only last two fields?

Comment: yea only the last two list.focused  and list.random_field